# visual studio 2010 database in LAN

Tags: database

I have 2 computers, one in Windows XP SP3 and another one in WIndows 7 Ultimate.

So I'm trying to create a Windows Application and a database to store items.
The PC with Windows XP will be using the same Windows Application but how am I going to connect to the database which is created in Windows 7?

Comment: What kind of database? That will determine how the Windows application will connect.

Comment: microsoft sql server 2008 which is included in visual studio 2010 package, and i chose microsoft sql server when choosing the type of database

Comment: There is nothing special about the scenario you posted. Just using the connection string should work _depending on the networking configuration_. Since this appears to be the first time you've done this, it's quite possible there's a problem with that configuration. Please post the _full_ exception that you are receiving. Catch the exception and display the result of `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to open the corresponding port of the firewall, and use ip and port to access to the database.

Comment: i used windows authentication but it won't allow me to connect, error popping out.

Comment: Application connects remotely sql server, it is best to use sql server authentication mode, i think.